# PyQT phonon volume slider? how to connect it on my phonon player

Tags: python, pyqt4, volume, phonon

Hi i have made a simple program that plays a video file,
i used QT Designer in creating the UI of my program
i have manage to make it play a video, and also connecting the seekslider too

my problem now is that. i cant make my volumnSlider work with the phonon player..

in my research this is how to connect it

```
self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
```

self.ui.volumeSlider is my volumeslider (using QT Designer)

what im missing is.. what self.audioOutput is?

doing some research i found this codes

```
self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
Phonon.createPath(self.mediaObject, self.audioOutput)
```

my problem in this is that. the volumnslider is made through codes(but mines is made on QT designer)

i dont know if im doing the wrong thing.. im trying now to find a way to covert this

```
Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
```

to a self.audioOutput that i need. please help me out guys, thanks

EDIT:

This my code on that part

```
    self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
    Phonon.createPath(self.ui.videoPlayer.mediaObject(), self.audioOutput) 
    self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
```

EDIT:

Heres the solution to this problem.. thanks to Avaris.

```
    #self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
    #Phonon.createPath(self.ui.videoPlayer.mediaObject(), self.audioOutput) 
    self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())
```

i have commented the first two lines. since its not needed anymore.
thanks again

Comment: It might be better if you showed your _actual_ code.

Comment: hi i added the part of code where im having the problem. thanks.

Comment: OK, I'm not that familiar with phonon but I might give this a go. Is `self.ui.videoPlayer` an instance of `Phonon.VideoPlayer`? If it is `VideoPlayer` has its own `AudioOutput`. Try changing the last line to `self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())` and get rid of the first two lines.

Comment: Avaris.. your amazing.. IT WORKS!!! thank you soo much for the skills on debuging... really im amazed. thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help :). Instead of editing your question with the answer you can write an answer to your own question (and accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the solution to this problem.. thanks to Avaris.

```
#self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
#Phonon.createPath(self.ui.videoPlayer.mediaObject(), self.audioOutput) 
self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())
```

i have commented the first two lines. since its not needed anymore. thanks again